# I need help getting all the JSON data API provides

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

Hello can you help me get array of all the data including global_rank, brawlhalla_id, etc.? I am only able to get array of legend like legend_id, legend_key_name. This is the json

```
{
    "name": "bmg | dan",
    "brawlhalla_id": 2,
    "rating": 1745,
    "peak_rating": 1792,
    "tier": "Platinum 2",
    "wins": 207,
    "games": 391,
    "region": "US-E",
    "global_rank": 5698,
    "region_rank": 1644,
    "legends": [
        {
            "legend_id": 4,
            "legend_name_key": "cassidy",
            "rating": 1736,
            "peak_rating": 1792,
            "tier": "Platinum 1",
            "wins": 161,
            "games": 300
        },
        {
            "legend_id": 21,
            "legend_name_key": "barraza",
            "rating": 1640,
            "peak_rating": 1640,
            "tier": "Gold 5",
            "wins": 41,
            "games": 77
        }
    ],
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

class BrawlhallaSevice {
    let url = URL(string: "http://sion.red/brawlhalla/ranked.json")!
    
    func getBrawlhalla(completion: @escaping (Result<[Brawlhalla], Error>) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(self.getBrawlhallaResponse(fromData: data!)))
        }.resume()
    }
    
    
    private func getBrawlhallaResponse(fromData data: Data) -> [Brawlhalla] {
        let brawlhallaData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BrawlhallaResponse.self, from: data)
        if let brawlhallaD = brawlhallaData {
            print(brawlhallaD)
         //return brawlhallaD.legends works and returns array of data about a legend
            return brawlhallaD
    
            
        }
        return [Brawlhalla(legend_name_key: "Error", rating: 0, peak_rating: 0, tier: "Error")]
    }
}
```

But it throws an error: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'BrawlhallaResponse' to return type '[Brawlhalla]'".
This is how my models look

```
import Foundation

struct BrawlhallaResponse: Codable {
    let legends: [Brawlhalla]
    let name: String
    let rating: Int
    let peak_rating: Int
    let tier: String
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Brawlhalla: Codable {
    let name: String
    let rating: Int
    let peak_rating: Int
    let tier: String
}
```

I have tried many changes to the code but nothing seem to work.

Comment: `Brawlhalla` has a `name: String` property, which doesn't appear in the JSON

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. I want an array that has all of the data available, but I can only show .legends. I want the data that are on the top of the json file like: name, region etc.

Comment: Paste your JSON data into https://app.quicktype.io to generate the structs you need.

Comment: @DavidMartinek, I mean that in JSON, in the `legends: [ ]` array, the objects don't have a property `name`, but in your code, `legends` maps to `[Brawlhalla]`, which does have the property `name`

Comment: That is possible. I am kinda new

Comment: The problem should be somewhere in getBrawlhallaResponse I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the right code, but it seems like you're trying to return brawhallaD in that if let statement. You're getting the error because your return type is [Brawlhalla], but you're returning a decodedResponse of type BrawlhallaResponse.

So what you can do is this:

```
class BrawlhallaSevice {
let url = URL(string: "http://sion.red/brawlhalla/ranked.json")!

func getBrawlhalla(completion: @escaping (Result<BrawlhallaResponse?, Error>) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(error!))
            return
        }
        guard let safeData = data else { return }
        completion(.success(self.getBrawlhallaResponse(fromData: safeData)))
    }.resume()
}


private func getBrawlhallaResponse(fromData data: Data) -> BrawlhallaResponse?{
    let brawlhallaData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BrawlhallaResponse.self, from: data)
    if let brawlhallaD = brawlhallaData {
        return brawlhallaD // Will return BrawlhallaResponse.peak_rating and also legends
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: This code throws me an error in my timeline https://pastebin.com/bt7XrncJ on line 9
"Cannot assign value of type 'BrawlhallaResponse?' to type '[BrawlhallaResponse]'"

Comment: BrawlhallaResponse isn't an array. you're returning type [BrawhallaResponse] when you should only return type BrawlhallaResponse. remove the brackets and it will work

Comment: Then it gives me this error: https://imgur.com/KoZjSl6